# What would be faster: addition w/ loop or w/o loop?

Tags: c#, loops, optimization

What would be faster: addition w/ loop or w/o loop (C#)?
I mean

```
int a=0;
for (int i=1;i<4;i++)
    a+=2*i;
```

or

```
int a=0;
a+=2*1;
a+=2*2;
a+=2*3;
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, only readability and maintainability matters. So use the loop

Comment: On modern CPUs you will see no difference, since your loop branches are free. And even if they werent, you'd have to loop so ridiculously often to see a difference, that serial execution is not an option.

Comment: if you wanted speed use a formula, not brute force.

Comment: Both are woeful cf. the obvious closed form solution. Although the second way is more explicitly compile time evaluable - perhaps a good C or C++ compiler would have better chance optimising the latter. I don't know anything about the capabilities of the C# compiler.

Comment: Obligatory [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Race your horses yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this progression,

```
n |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 
--------------------------------
a |  0 |  2 |  6 | 12 | 20 | 30
```

the closed form is,

```
a = n(1+n);
```

this will always be more efficient than any brute force approach. If efficiency doesn't matter then the closed form is still easier to read.

If you don't have the time to work out the closed form, for all but the shortest iterations, the loop is less typing. That's why we have them in the language, right?

Comment: Improving algorithms is always better than micro-optimization (especially when done without profiling)

Answer (score -1):

If you account for number of clock cycles used then implementation without the loop is faster since

```
int a=0;                   - 1
for (int i=1;i<4;i++)      - 11
    a+=2*i;                (1+11 = 12 clock cycles)
```

where as

```
int a=0;                   - 1
a+=2*1;                    - 1
a+=2*2;                    - 1
a+=2*3;                    - 1 (1+1+1+1 = 4 clock cycles)
```

But it doesn't really matter since clock frequencies are in gigahertz and this is almost negligible and the fact that compiler re-assembles your code during compile time which is in its optimized version.

Comment: This completely ignores compiler optimizations and makes lots of assumptions about the clock cycles each step requires (e.g.: why is `a+=2*2;` only a single cycle?)

Comment: I think you might need some other clock cycles for stuff like writing to registers and bounds checking etc. Perhaps a more logical term would be better.